# rspec error：uninitialized constant MockRequest

Tags: rspec, sinatra, rack

```
[root@cg sinatra-blog]#rspec app_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) blog should show index correctly
     Failure/Error: @req = MockRequest.new(Sinatra::Application)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant MockRequest
     # ./app_spec.rb:4
```

What's this?

Answer (score 0):

MockRequest is a helper class that helps testing without actually issuing an HTTP request.

app_spec.rb doesn't load Rack::MockRequest.

To fix this error, add

`require 'rack/mock'`

And change `MockRequest.new` to `Rack::MockRequest.new`.